# Can't bind events to inputs within jquery.steps wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I am using the Wizard from http://www.jquery-steps.com/. Everything with the wizard works pretty smooth, but when I try to bind an event to the input fields within that wizard, it is not working. The following is the essential code for the issue:

```
<div class="content">
            <h1>Basic Demo</h1>


            <div id="wizard">
                <h2>First Step</h2>
                <section>
                    <input type="text" class="namer" />

                    <div class="text">This should be replaced</div>

                <h2>Second Step</h2>
                <section>
                    <pdfsgdf</p>
                </section>

            </div>
        </div>

<script>
$(".namer").change(function(e){
  $(".text").html($(this).val()); 
});

$(function ()
                {
                    $("#wizard").steps({
                        headerTag: "h2",
                        bodyTag: "section",
                        transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
                    });
                });

</script>
```

And the JSFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/m23px/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like when the wizard is loaded, its changing the event listener.  You will need to listen for the event on the `#wizard` instead.

Try this:

```
$("#wizard").on('change','.namer',function(){
    $(".text").html($(this).val());     
});
```

Note:  If you want the change to happen as the user is typing, instead of after the field loses focus you can use the `keyup` event instead.

```
$("#wizard").on('keyup','.namer',function(){
    $(".text").html($(this).val());     
});
```

Comment: simple solution and working well,,, thank you from 2018 :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify why this is happening - in the `render` function (line 892), the content of the wizard is removed using `.empty()` and thus any listeners bound to elements inside it are lost.

```
wizard.attr("role", "application").empty().append(stepsWrapper).append(contentWrapper)
    .addClass(options.cssClass + " " + options.clearFixCssClass + verticalCssClass);
```

So there are three options to solve this, the first is to do as [Trevor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1022305/trevor) said and bind your listeners to either the wizard element or some element above it in the DOM.

The second is to add a callback for when the plugin has finished loading and initialise your listeners as normal at that point.

The third is to change the `render` function to use the original html (and therefore the original listeners), like so:

```
function render(wizard, options, state) {
    // Create a content wrapper and copy HTML from the intial wizard structure
    var contentWrapperTemplate = "<{0} class=\"{1}\"></{0}>",
        stepsWrapperTemplate = "<{0} class=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>",
        orientation = getValidEnumValue(stepsOrientation, options.stepsOrientation),
        verticalCssClass = (orientation === stepsOrientation.vertical) ? " vertical" : "",
        contentWrapper = $(contentWrapperTemplate.format(options.contentContainerTag, "content " + options.clearFixCssClass)),
        stepsWrapper = $(stepsWrapperTemplate.format(options.stepsContainerTag, "steps " + options.clearFixCssClass, "<ul role=\"tablist\"></ul>"));

    // Transform the wizard wrapper by wrapping the innerHTML in the content wrapper, then prepending the stepsWrapper
    wizard.attr("role", "application").wrapInner(contentWrapper).prepend(stepsWrapper)
        .addClass(options.cssClass + " " + options.clearFixCssClass + verticalCssClass);

    //Now that wizard is tansformed, select the the title and contents elements
    var populatedContent = wizard.find('.content'),
        stepTitles = populatedContent.children(options.headerTag),
        stepContents = populatedContent.children(options.bodyTag);

    // Add WIA-ARIA support
    stepContents.each(function (index) {
        renderBody(wizard, state, $(this), index);
    });

    stepTitles.each(function (index) {
        renderTitle(wizard, options, state, $(this), index);
    });

    refreshStepNavigation(wizard, options, state);
    renderPagination(wizard, options, state);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs :) may i know, how to add a callback ? with some sample code

Comment: This answer ended an entire week of agonizing and wrangling for me.  Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

The event won't fire until the focus is off of the input.

Use a `keyup` event instead.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MV2dn/5/

Comment: Yes, but it still won't change in the case with the wizard enabled. It works fine in your example though because you don't have the wizard. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem call steps code before your other code when the page is ready so that your bindings are not lost when Steps does its work